# Destination aliases with ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is it possible to define destination aliases with activemq artemis.
Our need is be able to have 2 different names for the same destination and consumers/producers can decide to use any of the 2 names.

We used to do it with ActiveMQ classic with a custom plugin that was changing the destination for the messages, the producers and the consumers.

For example, if we have dest1 and dest2 as an alias of dest1. Messages sent to dest2 were changed to dest1, producers/consumers connecting to dest2 were forced to connect to dest1 by the plugin.

Is there a way to do the same with Artemis?
I read the divert documentation which seems ok for the message part, but not sure how to handle the producer/consumer subscription part.

Thanks for you help.
Regards
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't have any built-in support for address or queue aliases, but it does have the same kind of [plugin infrastructure](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/broker-plugins.html) as ActiveMQ Classic so it's likely you can re-implement your functionality.